# Add flag to the Entitlement.plist in XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

Is it possible to add beta-reports-active flag to the Entitlement.plist?
I need this flag for beta testing. I tried regenerate my provision profiles, but this doesn't work, there is no such flag in the Entitlements(tried 10 times):

Entitlements

```
<key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
<string>QQQAAAQQQ</string>

<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
  <string>QQQAAAQQQ.*</string>
</array>

<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>QQQAAAQQQ.com.myappid</string>

<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: Was try to do this just this morning, and mine was added automatically. First time doing it.

Comment: Make sure you have everything enabled in iTunes Connect.